# Python requests downloading page html content instead of .xlsx file

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am attempting to download a .xlsx file from https://matmatch.com/ using Python Requests, however I am having issues with my script downloading the html content of the page rather than the xlsx document I want. I have used LivehttpHeaders to look at the requests the page is making and I found the get command the page is sending to download the file

`http://matmatch.com/api/downloads/materials/MITF1194/xlsx?expires-in=30min&download-token=cd21d8a7-ba5e-037e-f830-08600989cb0a`

Using this in python with a request.get command still results in downloading the raw html instead of the file. Here is the code I am currently using

```
import requests

url = "https://matmatch.com/api/downloads/materials/MITF1194/xlsx?expires-in=30min&download-token=360f528b-53be-72c1-25dd-dcf9401633a3"
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('copper.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Are there any glaring issues in my code or am I just not understanding how html works?
Cheers

EDIT: Here is the page I am trying to download from using the "download as .xlsx" button
https://matmatch.com/materials/mitf1194-astm-b196-grade-c17200-tb00

EDIT: Here is the LivehttpHeaders summary of the GET request. Do I need to include some of these headers in my request?

```
GET /api/downloads/materials/MITF1194/xlsx?expires-in=30min&download-token=41db0a0e-5091-0b06-8195-f0e0639286d6 HTTP/1.1
Host: matmatch.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mitf1194-astm-b196-grade-c17200-tb00.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Date: Mon, 22 Mar 2021 00:37:42 GMT
Expires: 0
Filename: mitf1194-astm-b196-grade-c17200-tb00.xlsx
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains;
transfer-encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: your url needs to have xlsx destination, in other other words the url you are accessing is not the actual destination of the excel file

Comment: Is there a way I can find the actual destination?

Comment: I think there is a redirect happening  after you visit this url with token http://matmatch.com/api/downloads/materials/MITF1194/xlsx?expires-in=30min&download-token=cd21d8a7-ba5e-037e-f830-08600989cb0a

Comment: Facing the same issue here.